# Django download via FileResponse or HttpResponse breaks csrf

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

In Django I'm trying to make a view that includes these two things:

- a link to generate and download a file via `FileResponse`
- a form to upload a file (posts to a separate view function)

If the user uses those things in that order, django returns 403 csrf error.

Some things I've tried, but still get csrf error:

- returning `HttpResponse` instead of `FileResponse`
- posting to the same view function
- setting `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True` for session-based instead of cookie-based csrf protection

I'm curious to understand why this is happening and how to properly build this view.

I am aware that `@csrf_exempt` can be used if csrf protection is not important.